# Excel VBA Performance - Can UDFs remember values?

Tags: excel, vba, user-defined-functions

I use a VBA "User Defined Function" in Excel like this:

```
Public Function GetValue(n)
    GetValue=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,n).Value2
End Function
```

Is there a way to make Excel remember the output for a specific value of n?

E.g. if there are mutiple cells with the formula "=GetValue(2)", then VBA should not look again in Sheet1 to get the corresponding value, but instead uses the stored value from Memory.

*Remark*: My function is more complicated than this example. It involves some if/else conditions on the value of n, to decide which cell it should read out.

Comment: The STATIC keyword may help here?

Comment: How would you then manage changes in sheet1 cells?

Comment: *but instead uses the stored value from Memory.* Variables are exactly for that. Something like `MyVar=Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,n).Value2` will store that value into `MyVar` so with just calling `MyVar` will output that value.

Comment: But i call the function GetValue(2) not the "function intern" variable GetValue.

Comment: Use a Procedure and not a UDF to populate values in those cells. If the cells are blank then only populate those cells

Comment: Seems like premature optimization to me. The task of looking up a value is small, and adding logic for caching the lookups will probably not improve speed in a substantial way.